# Do things that “get one’s rocks off ” always “rock one’s socks off ”?

Tags: etymology, idioms, dialects

I see both of these two phrases used quite often and I have to question why *rocks* are so cool here. Is there a history behind both of these sayings, and is possible that both of them are just mere propagandistic marketing blather by [Gary Dahl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Dahl_%28pet_rocks%29)?

How do you decide which one to use? In Texas, I hear both of them interchangeably.

> That horse will *rock your socks off.*

or,

> That horse will *get your rocks off.*

Comment: The second one sounds like it might be illegal in most countries.

Comment: @5arx *...keep it cool, keep it cool...*

Comment: @cornbreadninja sorry. It reminded me of this a lot:  http://i.imgur.com/wmPP0.png

Comment: @5arx LOL!  I was quoting part of Emerson, Lake & Palmer's [Karn Evil #9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karn_Evil_9), specifically the part about 'seven virgins and a mule'.  :D

Answer (score 13):

To *get one’s rocks off* is to become sexually excited.  If a horse does this to you, you should probably seek professional help.

To *rock your socks off* is to have a good time.  There is no sexual connotation to this expression, as far as I’m aware.

Comment: I have heard both used in a sexual manner, though I have never heard "get one's rocks off" used any other way than sexually!

Comment: I haven't heard it used as "sexually excited", I heard it to become sexually spent.

Comment: Here *rocks* = *stones* = *testicles*.